# The name of function "mem_fun_t"

Tags: c++, stl

What does the "t" prefix of `mem_fun_t` of STL stand for?

The difference between `mem_fun` and `mem_fun_t` is that the first one is a function returning an object of the second one, but how it "t" related to being a class?

Comment: Keep in mind that POSIX reserved the `_t` suffix for any use, so don't create any new types yourself that end in `_t`, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02

Comment: ?! Why wouldn't they put everything in a `posix::` namespace and not pollute the root namespace? (alternatively, I suppose we should be putting things in application-specific namespaces rather than the root namespace)

Comment: @Jason Because they use C, not C++.

Comment: then there should be an `#ifdef __cplusplus \n namespace posix {`

Comment: @Jason How do you expect linking to work? Should they also go out of their way for each and every language that is interoperable with C but has a superior namespace/module/package mechanism?

Comment: @Luc: oh. good point. [rescind]

Comment: @Luc Danton: yes, for any language that's sufficiently C-like to understand `#include`, `#ifdef`, `extern "C"` etc. No if "interoperable" just means being able to call C functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`t` is for *type*. (nullptr_t is the type of `nullptr`, `mem_fun_t` is the type of `mem_fun.`size_t` is the *type* used to denote object sizes and so on)

Answer (score 2):

t suffix: could it be..... "type"?